Visual Studio 2022 unable to debug T-SQL
When debugging a T-SQL procedure with Visual Studio 2022 we receive the error message:

Unable to start the Transact-SQL-debugger, could not connect to the Database Engine instance '"my-instance"'. Make sure you have enabled the debugging firewall exceptions are using a login that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.


Using SSMS v17.9.1 debugging works.
We do not have any firewalls setup for the remote DB server and for the local server, so no rules are setup as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/configure-firewall-rules-before-running-the-tsql-debugger?view=sql-server-ver16
the user is a member of the sysadmin group, IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin') = 1
SSDT is installed in Visual Studio, DB connections can be made and stored procedures can be "executed" to compile on the DB

What could be the issue?
Is the debugging connection with SSMS and Visual Studio different?

There isn't a VS 2024..? The latest download is still VS 2022.

Which version are you trying to debug with? I have Version 17.3.4 community ed. and debugging works fine there

Using Visual Studio version 17.9.6 (latest)

What is the SSMS version that you encounter the issue, 20.1?

SSMS supports debugging only till v17.9.1. Just mentioned that it works with SSMS. I would like to use Visual Studio for debugging
